# How restricted are tourists coming to Japan as part of an organized tour?

Tags: covid-19, japan

Japan is still only allowing tourists to enter on a group/package tour. If you arrive as part of a group tour ([for example this one](https://alljapantours.com/japan-group-tours/trip-detail/best-of-japan-tour-summer-reverse/?an=sear#topsear)), would you be **legally** obligated to stay with the tour guide? Or could you just make use of the prepaid hotel but otherwise travel around entirely on your own?

[This page](https://www.japan.travel/en/practical-coronavirus-information/tourists/) says you must wear masks when instructed by your tour guide but doesn't mention if you're allowed to do activities without the tour guide present. Note that I'm primarily interested in the *letter* of the law, not the *spirit* of the law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is now more or less moot as Japan has announced they'll allow unguided tourists [to visit the country](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2022/08/31/national/tourism-measures-kishida-covid/):

> Prime Minister Fumio Kishida said Wednesday that Japan will allow the entry of nonescorted visitors on package tours and raise the daily arrival cap to 50,000 starting Sept. 7 — a significant step toward the full resumption of tourism.

So you'll still need to buy a packaged tour but won't need an escort and would be free to do whatever you want. They're also removing the PCR test requirement for vaccinated people:

> Last week, Kishida said Japan will drop pre-arrival PCR tests from Sept. 7 if passengers have received three shots of an approved vaccine.

Comment: +1, but you're not entirely free: you need to stay at designated hotels and are expected to stick to the itinerary. It's all on an honor basis, but you *could* potentially be in hot water if you're somehow busted off track.

Comment: @lambshaanxy right but if I understand correctly you could just put "get drinks in Shibuya" in your itinerary if you want to do that. The more annoying part is that visa waivers are still not back.

Answer (score 9):

According to the Japanese Ministry of Land, Infrastructure and Tourism:

- The tour conductor should "Ensure compliance with infection prevention measures throughout the tour."
- The tour conductor should "Keep a record of the tour participants' activities."
- The traveler should "follow the instructions given by the tour conductor."
- "Failure to comply with the above may result in you not being allowed to participate in or continue on the tour.
  You may also be required to immediately return to your home country during the tour"

So you **Legally** have to follow the tour conductor instructions. And you can't visit on your own if the tour conductor is against you doing activities alone.

The question is if there is a tour conductor that would not be against you visiting and touring japan on your own agenda.
It seems very unlikely as that would go against the first two items of the bullet point since he would not be monitoring you but rather just taking your word that you will respect preventive measures and report all activities you do truthfully. And they would not take risk just for you, they sold a guided tour and that's the extent of what they have to provide.

Sources:
https://www.mlit.go.jp/kankocho/en/shisaku/kokusai/content/001489999.pdf
https://www.mlit.go.jp/kankocho/en/shisaku/kokusai/content/001486722.pdf

Comment: The one eyewitness report I recently read (can't find link, alas) said that they were left completely free in the evenings after the 'official' program ended.  So while not a free-for-all, there's also a lot of slack if the tour guide allows it.

Comment: A bit surprising, it seems Japan created their own version of Intourist.

Comment: Thanks. But are these legally binding rules or just “recommendations”? Would be nice to lookup the Japanese language regulation.

Comment: @JonathanReez What does "binding rule" mean to you? It states right there that failing to comply can result in you being deported from the country. This sounds legally binding to me. Or are you asking if it is considered a crime and you could be jailed? Note that being deported will certainly be recorded permanently in your passport/Japan customs and will probably influence future international travel (you will have to answer "yes" on forms asking if you were ever deported from a country).

Comment: @GACy20 often times the English translation or the website text are not accurate. If the English version matches the actual Japanese regulation then you’re right. But maybe it doesn’t and there isn’t actually a legally binding rule

Comment: "It states right there that failing to comply can result in you being deported from the country" Japan does this A LOT in their written language, and to be fair from time to time they do follow those written rules, but more often than not they don't care nor there will be consequences if you don't follow them or there will be huge holes as you shared. Of course it's still a risk and YMMV. I'd recommend trying to get a Business visa or just about any other kind instead if possible.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia yeah I’m looking into the business visa option currently. This is also the trick to get into Turkmenistan, another highly reclusive country.

Comment: @lambshaanxy if you find a link, that would be great! Finding the most lazy tour guide in the country could be one solution :-)